# Change Objects Attributes with a loop (Delphi 2010)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have 160 objects of the same type `TApdStatusLight`,
`TApdStatusLight1`, `TApdStatusLight2`,... `TApdStatusLight160`.
How can I change the NoLitColor with a for loop without having to write 160 lines to change every one?

Comment: Can you show some basic code you are having now?

Comment: Are those really 160 distinct class types? Or just 160 variables of 1 single type?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the instances dynamically, in a loop, rather than using the form designer. Do this in an overridden constructor of your form, or in an `OnCreate` event handler for the form.

Don't have 160 fields each holding a reference to the instances. Instead hold them in an array. That way if you need to apply changes to all of the instances, you can do so in a loop.